# How to retrieve specific column value from foreign key table?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There are two Models. One is `TradeLicence` and another is `BusinessCategory`.
I have already established relationship between them. In `TradeLicence` there is a foreign key `category_id` which local key is `id` of `BusinessCategory`.

Trade Licence Model

```
class TradeLicence extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['slug', 'name', 'category_id'];

    public  function businessCategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BusinessCategory::class,'category_id','id');
    }

}
```

`trade_licences` migration Table:

```
    class CreateTradeLicencesTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('trade_licences', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();

            $table->foreignId->('category_id');
            $table->string->('name');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
     }
}
```

Business Category Model:

```
class BusinessCategory extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $fillable = ['slug', 'name', 'fees'];
}
```

`business_categories` migration table:

```
class CreateBusinessCategoriesTable extends Migration
```

{

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('business_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('slug')->unique();

        $table->string('name');
        $table->double('fees');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

For adding a "Trade Licence", I need to select a "Business Category" and it stores the value
in`category_id` column of `trade_licences`table. I'm able to retrieve the `name` and `fees` value through the relationship inside `TradeLicense` model.

The problem is:

There is a another Model named `DailyEarning`. The `show()` method of `DailyEarningController` will display `fees` amount (fee of selected category, which was selected at the time of creating a new trade licence) and `created_at` and `updated_at` value of each Trade License.

My Question is:

How to get the values of `fees`, `created_at` and `updated_at` or which Query should I use to retrieve the values  by using "Eloquent"?

Comment: what is the relation between DailyEarning and BusinessCategory ?

Comment: There is no relationship between DailyEarning and BusinessCategory. BusinessCategory has relation with TradeLicence.
@HananAlhasan.